# Prevent image scaling on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image added to a web page. The image is of dimensions 320X248. But, when it renders on iphone safari, the image size is smaller. When I use an image of 640X496, it is rendered as 320X248. The same thing happens with Android Nexus. So is there a generic approach to ensure that my image is rendered at 320X248, in the default zoom state across all mobile browsers. Please note that I am not using meta tags to disable user scaling or zooming, in my web page.

```
      var divToAppendTo = ref.config.tarDiv;
      var new_html = '';
      var em_url = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D';
      var rand_id = 'inview_banner_image_' + Math.random();

      var new_html = 
          '<div  style="width:320px;height:248px;background-color:black;margin:0 auto;"   onclick="inviewEndBannerClicked()"' + '><img id="' + rand_id + '" src="' + em_url + '" style="width:320px;background-color:black;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"' + '></div>';

      divToAppendTo.innerHTML = new_html;
      if(ref.config.inview_bnr_url !== undefined && ref.config.inview_bnr_url) {
          var imageNode = document.getElementById(rand_id);
          imageNode.src = ref.config.inview_bnr_url;
      }
      else {
          //console.log('End banner url undefined!');
      }
```

Comment: Does your image have the 'max-width:100%' property? If it does, remove it since it causes the image to resize according to its container.

Comment: Other tan that, have you tried giving your image a fixed width of 320px and a fixed height of 248px in your stylesheet? Maybe forcing it, and even adding the '!important' clause might help

Comment: Sounds like there is some CSS that is doing image scaling for the Retina screen. But we will need to see some relevant code to be sure.

Comment: I haven't set max-width:100% for my image. Yes, I tried giving the image a fixed width of  320px and a fixed height of 248px, even with the !important, but still the same

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code where the div containing the image is appended to another div.

Comment: i solved the problem by modifying my new_html to this: var new_html = '<img src="' + em_url + '" ' + 'style="width:inherit;height:auto;background-color:red;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" id="' + rand_id + '"' +  '>';

Answer (score 0):

On mobile browsers there is a ratio of images to pixels, otherwise it would not scale correctly due to high DPI's commonly 1080p and websites being more common in 1280 x 1024.

Evidence of this can be easily found, for example in chrome developer tools press f12 goto the  emulation tab there you can select various devices and view the device pixel ratio, as you can see it's not the same across all devices, the only way to get your images to scale properly across all browsers, is to use percentages *NOTE* it does not only affect images but everything in you site will be rendered according to the devices pixel ratio.

set all your images to a percentages, 100% or otherwise to get them to scale accordingly

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by modifying my new_html to this:

```
var new_html = '<img src="' + em_url + '" ' + 'style="width:inherit;height:auto;background- color:red;display:block;margin-left‌​:auto;margin-right:auto" id="' + rand_id + '"' + '>';
```